# Compare a list of objects to an object

Tags: c#

I have a button <kbd>ADD CV</kbd>. When a user logs on to the website, I check a table `"cv" {id_member, id_cv}`, if the `id_member` exists already in the table, the <kbd>ADD CV</kbd> button is disabled, otherwise the user can click it.

I retrieve all `id_members` from DB in a list (`c`) of classes (`cv { int Id_candidat}`). I need to check for the existence of logged user's id in this list (extracted from the `Session` variable).

This how I do it, but it's not working:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<cv> c = new List<cv>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=p5-pc\sqlexpress;" + 
              "Initial Catalog=recrutement_online_3;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select id_candidat from cv";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        cv p3 = new cv();
        p3.Id_candidat = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
        c.Add(p3);        
    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    cv r = new cv();
    r.Id_candidat = int.Parse(Session["Id_candidat"].ToString());
    if (c.Contains(r))
    {
        Button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    ...
```

My question is, How can I check for the existance of logged user's cv in database?

Comment: You should work on your variable naming. What is `c` or `r` supposed to represent to somebody that has never seen your code before?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Its quite hard to read with the short variable names

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: well c is a list of object type cv and cv is a classe with one attribute "private  int id_mmber" r is an variable type cv too that took the session id and now i wanna compare the session id to the collection if already exist teh buton1 is disabled

Comment: -1 cause no real question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for candidate existence when filling the list of available cvs:

```
...
bool candidatExists = false;
int idCandidat = int.Parse(Session["Id_candidat"].ToString());
while (dr.Read())
    {
        cv p3 = new cv();
        p3.Id_candidat = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
        c.Add(p3);
        if(p3.Id_candidat == idCandidat)
        {
             candidatExists = true;
        }
    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    Button1.Enabled = !candidatExists;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) to check for the existence of the candidate ID in the CV's list assuming that you've exposed a non private id member of your `cv` class (you haven't been clear):

```
bool showAddCvBtn = c.Any(id => id.id_member == r.Id_candidat);
```